# Запрос с использованием  внешних ключей, вынесенных в отдельную таблицу

Tags: mysql, sql

Хочу понять принцип, поэтому привожу абстрактный пример: 
Есть таблица boy:

```
CREATE TABLE `boy` (
`BOY_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`BOY_NAME` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`BOY_ID`)
```

)

Есть таблица toy:

```
CREATE TABLE `toy` (
`TOY_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`TOY_TITLE` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`TOY_ID`)
```

)

Есть таблица link:

```
CREATE TABLE `link` (
`LINK_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`BOY_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`TOY_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`LINK_ID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK__boy` FOREIGN KEY (`BOY_ID`) REFERENCES `boy` (`BOY_ID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK__toy` FOREIGN KEY (`TOY_ID`) REFERENCES `toy` (`TOY_ID`)
```

)
Последняя таблица содержит связь внешних ключей таблиц toy и boy. Каким запросом можно получить соответствующие друг другу  boy.BOY_NAME и toy.TOY_TITLE. Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так, например,

```
select BOY_NAME, TOY_TITLE  
from boy natural join link natural join toy
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я понял

Answer (score 1):

select b.boy_name,t.toy_name from link l join boy b on l.boy_id=b.boy_id join toy t on l.toy_id=t.toy_id как-то так